# Lonesome Cowboy hat and other hats are not showing in winter bash

Tags: discussion, badges, winter-bash-2013

Why I am not getting `Lonesome Cowboy` Hat for the site Stackoverflow?

[image]

I see only one winter bash hat :(

Though i got Tumbleweed badge in my [SO profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1559213/murali?tab=badges)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to earn the Tumbleweed badge *during* Winterbash, but you got it in August 2012.